# Why does 'unanswered' tab shows answered questions?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, unanswered-questions

When I click on 'unanswered' tab in the menu of this site, it includes all the questions already answered. Any specific reason or am I missing something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check the label at the top right:

[image]

Until somebody, anybody, says "This is a useful answer" the question is regarded as Unanswered.

Comment: Yup, this is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, including one question with **six** answers!

[image: Unanswerd?!]

Very curious indeed...

I just checked other Stack Exchange sites I belong to, and none of them exhibited this phenomenon.

Comment: Meep, 6 answers and no upvotes? We'd better rectify that, one way or another!