# Why 'Unanswered' shows Questions with 'Unselected' Answers and not Questions with ZERO answers?

Tags: feature-request

When I click on *unanswered* to sort out the questions, it gives me the list of questions *with answers*. But [then I learned](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/870/why-does-unanswered-tab-shows-answered-questions) that *unanswered* means **no answer is selected** by the original poster.

I feel this should be corrected by replacing the word **unanswered** to **unselected**. That's because if OP is inactive (or for that sake even leaves the ELL site forever!), the question **will still remain** unanswered though it may have **the answer** with accurate and researched content.

On the other hand, clicking on *active* returns questions with zero answers **as well!** I understand that on this site, all questions are *always active* as anyone can answer the question which is already answered (a green tick) but then to avoid ambiguity, this should be **redefined.**

It should be...

> **Unanswered -** Questions with ZERO answer. The question is **not answered yet.**
>   **Active-** Questions with answers but no answer selected by the OP, it's still **active.** 
>   **Unselected -** Questions with **no selected answer.**

Also, is there any way I can view the questions with ZERO answer as of now?

Comment: To see questions with no Answers, select the 'Unanswered' link in the **upper** menu, next to 'Ask Question'. The **lower** menu will then display the choices 'my tags', 'newest', 'votes' and **'no answers'**.

Comment: @StoneyB Oh, I completely missed that! I focused all time on the mid-screen area!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are confusing the user 'accepted' answer feature with questions that are 'unanswered'.

A question is considered "answered" when it receives an answer **with at least one up-vote.**

Have a look at this blog post:

[**OK, Now Define “Answered”**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/ok-now-define-answered/).

But the "accepted answer" feature does serve the purposes you are attributing to it. The *accepted answer* feature is simply a social convention to indicate which answer the ***author*** found most helpful. A question is not considered *answered* by ticking it off. The best answer is determined by the community vote.

Unfortunately, your misunderstanding is very common, which is why I'm not a big fan of the feature in the first place.